# How to Subclass UIView and then how to use it with drawRect to draw graphics?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

How to Subclass `UIView` and then how to use it with `drawRect` to draw graphics?
Do I need to add the framework and then include in the header file QuartzCore or any other?

---

Combined solutions:

---

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface drawingViewController : UIViewController {
}
@end
```

---

```
#import "drawingViewController.h"
#import "myview.h"
@implementation drawingViewController
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0,0,340,480);  
    myview *ui = [[myview alloc] initWithFrame:rect];
    [self.view addSubview:ui];
}
```

---

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface myview : UIView {
}
@end
```

---

```
#import "myview.h"
@implementation myview
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code.
    }
    return self;
}


// Only override drawRect: if you perform custom drawing.
// An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    // Drawing code.
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGContextAddArc(context, 50, 50, 50, 0, 30, 0);
CGContextFillPath(context);

    //set the fill or stroke color
    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 1, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0);
    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(context, 0.5, 1, 0.5, 1.0);

    //fill or draw the path
    CGContextDrawPath(context, kCGPathStroke);
    CGContextDrawPath(context, kCGPathFill);

    ------------------------------
    CGContextAddArc(context, 100, 100, 20, 0, 30, 0);

    //set the fill or stroke color
    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 1, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0);
    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(context, 0.5, 1, 0.5, 1.0);

    //fill or draw the path
    CGContextDrawPath(context, kCGPathStroke);
    CGContextDrawPath(context, kCGPathFill);

}
```

---

other things to note:

[Drawing triangle/arrow on a line with CGContext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2500197/drawing-triangle-arrow-on-a-line-with-cgcontext)

[CGContext Optimization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1205345/cgcontext-optimization)

[iPhone clear CGContext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2090217/iphone-clear-cgcontext)

[Saving and restoring CGContext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1446446/saving-and-restoring-cgcontext)

[How do I draw a line on the iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/856354/how-do-i-draw-a-line-on-the-iphone)

[How to draw string in other device orientations using CGContext iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6558764/how-to-draw-string-using-cgcontext-ios)

Comment: why do you want to subclass UIView ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in .h file

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
@interface YourView : UIView {
```

...

in .m file

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect{
    CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    //your drawings
}
```

then call `setNeedsDisplay` to redraw the rect